# HttpsURLConnection not working on Android API 19 (but works on API 22 through 29)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, networking

So I'm lost here. I make HttpsURLConnection calls and it works fine on API 22 (emulator and actual device), API 23 (device) and API 29 (emulator). But it just won't work on API 19 (tried on both actual device and emulator).

```
public class HttpsCall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urlString){

        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(8000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            if (inputStream == null) return null;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            if (buffer.length() == 0) return null;
            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } finally{
            if (urlConnection != null) urlConnection.disconnect();
            if (reader != null) {
                try { reader.close(); }
                catch (final IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

minSdkVersion is 19 and permissions in Manifest seem in order:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I get no error, just a null response. When trying with https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos, I get the following in the console:

```
09-03 17:12:44.533 I/QCNEA   : |NIMS|: getaddrinfo: hostname api.github.com servname NULL numeric 4 appname /system/bin/app_process
09-03 17:12:44.533 I/QCNEA   : |NIMS|: getaddrinfo: hostname api.github.com servname NULL numeric 0 appname /system/bin/app_process
```

I get the message above when using the device, and nothing when using the emulator.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are catching the Exception, suppressing it, and then returning null. This will not help you debug the issue. You should log the exception (not in the finally block).

Comment: Note that Github's API is using TLS 1.2 and above only. The device running API level 19 may not have TLS enabled. Without any additional information, this would be one of the first things I'd check.

Comment: @DavidV indeed. Fixed that and I got "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer". It was indeed because TLS 1.2 was disabled.

Comment: The result of `getInputStream()` cannot be null, so there is no point in testing for it. Don't write pointless code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by David, the problem was that API 19 disables TLS 1.2 by default. Here's how to fix that: https://gist.github.com/Kane-Shih/2a556fd24604ed9e80d69581c4f912a3